# Laravel Nested Query

Tags: sql, laravel

i'm having hard time getting the right query for this in laravel.

I have table Exams.

```
id | exam_name 
---|------------
1  | First Exam
2  | Second Exam
3  | Third Exam
```

And Students score table

```
id  | exam_id | score
----|---------|-------
1   | 1       | 15
2   | 1       | 12
3   | 1       | 10
4   | 2       | 7
5   | 2       | 16
6   | 2       | 13
```

And i want to get the average scores for all exams that looks like

```
exam_name   | average_score
------------|--------------
First Exam  | 12.33
Second Exam | 12
Third Exam  | 0 or NULL
```

I have tried left join but it returns multiple rows per exam.
I can also think of using nested Query but don't know how it works in Laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DB::table('exams')
   ->leftJoin('student_score','exam_id','=','exams.id')
   ->select('exam_name', DB::raw('AVG(score) as average_score'))
   ->groupBy('exam_name')->get();
```

You can get the AVG score by using above query.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do the `left join` with `Students` table :

```
select e.exam_name, avg(s.score) avg_score 
from Exams e 
left join Students  s on s.exam_id = e.id
group by e.exam_name;
```

You can also use `subquery` with correlation approach

```
select *, 
       (select avg(s.score) from Students where e.exam_id = id) avg_score 
from Exams e;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to join tables at all. You can solve this with plain laravel.

```
// in your controller
$exams = Exam::with('students')->get();

// in your view you should replace this with blade
foreach ($exams as $exam) {
    $exam->students->avg('score'); // Average score for each exam
}
```

Your exam model should have:

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->hasMany(student::class);
}
```

and your students class must have the inverse relation:

```
public function exam() {
    return $this->belongsTo(exam::class);
}
```